# Google authorization oAuth 2.0 without popup and consent

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-api, oauth-2.0, authorization

I need to get auth code in JSON not in url after confirm popup google window.  I try do it like in this google docs https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

but this is doesnt work! What i do wrong ? Here is my code .

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=start" async defer></script>
<script>
    function start() {
        gapi.load('auth2', function() {
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '0101010101-p5a3fgbkeso3loqg157001l4deajshot.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                scope:'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
                    // Scopes to request in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
                    //scope: 'additional_scope'
            });
        });

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="signinButton">Sign in with Google</button>
<script>
    $('#signinButton').click(function() {
    // signInCallback defined in step 6.
    auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'}).then(function(resp) {
        var auth_code = resp.code;

    });
});
```

Comment: Found a solution ?